# How can I create a flat marker in Google maps 3d flash api?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, api, google-maps, 3d

When using map3d, the default marker creation is always perpendicular to the viewport.  How can I create a marker that lays down flat against the map?  I can't use GroundOverlay because it becomes overly tiny when the map is zoomed out.  How can I create a matrix3d object that will rotate/scale/skew my Marker's foreground DisplayObject so it remains flat against the map when in perspective mode?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this it possible in map component api. The best way is to create your own marker engine. Draw your marker in Sprite over the oryginal marker position.

Comment: Thanks Konrad.  I used the point transform stuff in the maps api to rotate and skew the points of my sprite to make it appear to sit on the map.